# How to remove blank screen before splash screen in Expo?

Tags: expo

I am working on react native project using expo framework. But when my app launches then before splash screen for small interval blank screen is shown.

Answer (score 0):

first delete the default icon and splash screen in the assets folder and replace them with your newly created custom splash screen and icon.then edit the `App.json` file to

```
"icon": "./assets/yourIconName.png", //the name of image in asset folder
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/yourSplashNmae.png", //the name of image in asset folder
  "resizeMode": "contain",
  "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
```

Comment: Let me check. Thanks for your reply

Comment: you try for ios or android ?because it works with me for android .Try to verify the extention of image

Comment: I tried for both. on iOS working fine but for android first blank screen is shown then splash screen is displayed

Comment: Try this  < "android":
      "splash": {
         "image": "./assets/yourSplashNmae.png", 
      },>

Comment: did not got your logic

Comment: "android":{
      "splash": {
      //your code
      }, },"ios":{
      "splash": {
      //your code
      }, }